# Can we retrieve any data from a device via Bluetooth?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, data-transfer, ecgi

I would like to get my hands on [**`Spyder Bluetooth wearable wireless ECG device`**](http://sandor.co.in/spyder/) and transmit the data to an *app*.

Now I'm fairly new to *Bluetooth communication*, so can someone please direct me to reliable source that can help me distinguish data-transmission via *Bluetooth*.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ask the manufacturer if they have an SDK for Android or some other form of developer guide for integrating with this device.

Comment: I doubt they do. However this device is not definitive for this question. If you know of any other device that provides ecg reading, please share? @CommonsWare

Answer (score 0):

Your best resource would be from Apple's Developer site. They have a few sample projects that do exactly what you are after as well as heaps of documentation.

You can find the documentation here:
https://developer.apple.com/bluetooth/

Edit: The above is for IOS, just noticed you are after an android solution as well. Someone else will need to point you in the right direction for that.